# PHP: Mysql column explode with prefix array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

i have an mysql column explode method

here is the code :

```
$barang2=mysql_query("select * from tbl_barang WHERE INDX=2");
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($barang2))    {              
    $result = "$c[DESKRIPSI]<br />";

    $rows = explode("#", $result);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
        $temp   = explode(':', $rows[$i]);
        $IDK    = $temp[1];
        $ID    = array("ID Kategori : ","Kategori : ","Warna : ","Ukuran : ","B : ");



        //echo '<br />' . $ID . ' : ';
        echo $ID[0]. ' : '. $IDK[0] . '<br />';
        echo $ID[1]. ' : '. $IDK[1] . '<br />';
        echo $ID[2]. ' : '. $IDK[2] . '<br />';
        echo $ID[3]. ' : '. $IDK[3] . '<br />';
        echo $ID[4]. ' : '. $IDK[4] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

i get the column on mysql where its like `IDK:16#K:BAJU#W:HITAM#U:L#B:120G`

then trying to get it like

```
ID Kategori : 16
Kategori : BAJU
Warna : HITAM
Ukuran : L
B : 120G
```

but i cant call the offset like `$IDK[0]` and join the first array...

Comment: STOP using `mysql_` functions as they have been deprecated. Switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`. (going with the theme). `$result` does not have rows in it, it is a single array. There is no need for a for loop here.

Comment: i try single echo like `echo $ID . ' : '. $IDK . '<br />';` but the `$ID` doesnt comes up with my every single array...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a delimited data structure in a field in the table. This tends to be horrible to process.

But if you really must use it then I think what you are trying to put out could be done like this:-

```
$barang2=mysql_query("select * from tbl_barang WHERE INDX=2");
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($barang2))    
{              
    $fields = explode("#", $c[DESKRIPSI]);

    $ID = array("ID Kategori : "=>'',"Kategori : ">'',"Warna : ">'',"Ukuran : ">'',"B : ">'');
    foreach($fields AS $field_key=>$field_value)
    {
        $temp   = explode(':', $field_value);
        switch($temp[0])
        {
            case 'IDK':
                $ID["ID Kategori : "] = $temp[1];
                break;
            case 'K':
                $ID["Kategori : "] = $temp[1];
                break;
            case 'W':
                $ID["Warna : "] = $temp[1];
                break;
            case 'U':
                $ID["Ukuran : "] = $temp[1];
                break;
            case 'B':
                $ID["B : ">''] = $temp[1];
                break;
            default:
                // nothing
                break;
        }

        foreach($ID AS $key=>$value)
        {
            echo $key. $value . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

But it would be better to redesign your database to avoid the issue in the first place.

Comment: it comes to be multiple `$key` and `$value` and echo an random number :(